# Magento robots.txt 404s

Tags: .htaccess, magento, robots.txt

I have a Magento multi-site installation.  I want to disallow just one of my stores, but not the others.  I am trying to take advantage of the "Default Robots" option on the Magento config, so I left the default robots to "Index,Follow" for all stores except the one I want to disallow, which I changed to "Noindex,Nofollow".  But when I go to my-URL/robots.txt, I get a 404 error.

Any idea why this might 404?

Can someone point my in the direction of how I might make a robots.txt that only disallows that one site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting will only add a meta robots tag to your pages, e.g.

```
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
```

See: http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html

The Magento application does not interface with your `robots.txt`

Comment: Do you think this is satisfactory for keeping bots off your site?  Or is it better to have a robots.txt file?

Comment: Also, is there a way to disallow only one store in robots.txt?

Comment: @JimmyPelton Not if they share the same document root.